# how many passengers will be on the bus two stops after the stop where it has its greatest number of passengers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The number of passengers on a certain bus at any given
time is given by the equation $P= -2(S-4)^2 + 32$, where
P is the number of passengers and S is the number of
stops the bus has made since beginning its route. If the
bus begins its route with no passengers, how many
passengers will be on the bus two stops after the stop
where it has its greatest number of passengers?

---

I dont know how to attempt this question,What $S$ should i put to get the asked $P?$

Comment: You should notice that this is a parabola. Try to recall all the properties about it. In particular, where is the maximum?

Comment: I got it,thanks.